# checked attribute not working in radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The radio button does not show up as checked by default. am trying to make my first option as checked by default. But it is not working.. any idea or suggestion?

```
<div Class ="form-group">
    <label>Select your Email Hierarchy</label>

    <div class="radio" ng-switch="deliveryMethod">
    <div ng-switch-when="email">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="delivery-email" name="delivery-email"
        ng-model="generated.delivery" ng-change="checkValidGenerate()"
        class="check" value="EE/ER" checked="checked"/>
     EE/ER
     </label><br/>
<!-- some code--other option listed -->
```

Comment: [It works fine when I test it](http://jsbin.com/gisiqi/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: works good enough.

Comment: @Quentin, unfortunately I have to go ahead and say: it doesn't work.. you provide a plunker without `Angular` library. And it can't work, because `checked` doesn't work since `ngModel` is probably **null**.

Comment: @developer033 — You mean the OP didn't provide a [MCVE]? (And plunker? JSBin is not plunker!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at first there's no necessity of the use of `checked`. It should work if you attribute the `value` to your `ngModel`, otherwise it won't work:

```
$scope.generated.delivery = 'EE/ER';
```

See the example below:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.deliveryMethod = 'email';
    $scope.generated = {};
    $scope.generated.delivery = 'EE/ER';
  }
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div Class="form-group">
    <label>Select your Email Hierarchy</label>
    <div class="radio" ng-switch="deliveryMethod">
      <div ng-switch-when="email">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" id="delivery-email" name="delivery-email" ng-model="generated.delivery" ng-change="checkValidGenerate()" value="EE/ER"> EE/ER
        </label>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```